# Использование системных бриджей

Tags: linux, сеть, centos, администрирование, docker

Есть хост с `centos 7` с бриджами

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.ee7e7157d54b   no      dummy0
br1     8000.f6ac6f4e2a36   no      dummy1
docker0     8000.02424e53c9d8   no
```

и с docker и его бриджами

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
616ab65930e0        bridge              bridge              local
1c2a207d6c31        host                host                local
fe0b1c8485e8        none                null                local
```

вопрос: Как заставить docker использовать системные бриджи? Пока смог найти только пример, где создают бридж через `docker network create` поверх системного, что, на мой взгляд, костыль. Есть ли какое-то нормальное решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# docker network create --driver=bridge --gateway=10.10.0.1 --subnet=10.10.0.0/24 --ip-range=10.10.0.2/24 -o "com.docker.network.bridge.name"="br1" -o "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4"="10.10.0.1" subnet1
```

При добавлении контейнера в сеть `subnet1` интерфейс будет в системном бридже

```
$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.b64adf033d1e   no      d0
                            d1
br1     8000.1e446a12cafe   no      vetheb5d250
docker0     8000.02424e53c9d8   no
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать networkmode "host".

> docker run --network host imagename

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings

Comment: Это не подходит. Необходимо либо с `driver=bridge` либо с `driver=macvlan`